# Is there a way to make RecyclerView requiresFadingEdge unaffected by paddingTop and paddingBottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Currently, I need to use `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom` of `RecyclerView`, as I want to avoid complex space calculation, in my first `RecyclerView` item and last item.

However, I notice that, `requiresFadingEdge` effect will be affected as well.

This is my XML

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"

    android:overScrollMode="always"
    android:background="?attr/recyclerViewBackground"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false" />
```

---

### When paddingTop and paddingBottom is 40dp

[image]

As you can see, the fading effect shift down by 40dp, which is not what I want.

---

### When paddingTop and paddingBottom is 0dp

[image]

Fading effect looks fine. But, I need to have non-zero `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom`, for my `RecyclerView`.

---

Is there a way to make `RecyclerView`'s `requiresFadingEdge` unaffected by `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom`?

Answer (score 39):

I found the best and kind of official solution for this. Override this 3 methods of `RecyclerView`. Which play most important role for fading edge.

First create your recyclerView.

```
public class MyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    // ... required constructor

    @Override
    protected boolean isPaddingOffsetRequired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getTopPaddingOffset() {
        return -getPaddingTop();
    }

    @Override
    protected int getBottomPaddingOffset() {
        return getPaddingBottom();
    }
}
```

That's it. Use this recyclerview and you will see fadding edge unaffected.

**Following content is just for explanation. If you want to know behind the scene.**

To understand how this edge effect is working I dig into the class where `android:requiresFadingEdge` is used, And I found that it's not handled by `RecyclerView` instead It's handled by `View` class which is parent for all view.

In `onDraw` method of `View` class I found the code for drawing fade edge by using  help of this method `isPaddingOffsetRequired`. Which used only for handling the fade effect.

According to documentation this method should be overridden by child class If you want to change the behaviour of fading edge. Bydefault It return `false`. So By returning `true` we are asking view to apply some offset for edge at the time of view drawing.

Look following snippet of `onDraw` method of `View` class to understand the calculation.

```
final boolean offsetRequired = isPaddingOffsetRequired();
if (offsetRequired) {
    paddingLeft += getLeftPaddingOffset();
}

int left = mScrollX + paddingLeft;
int right = left + mRight - mLeft - mPaddingRight - paddingLeft;
int top = mScrollY + getFadeTop(offsetRequired);
int bottom = top + getFadeHeight(offsetRequired);

if (offsetRequired) {
    right += getRightPaddingOffset();
    bottom += getBottomPaddingOffset();
}
```

As we can see `top` variable is initialize using `getFadeTop(offsetRequired)`.

```
protected int getFadeTop(boolean offsetRequired) {
    int top = mPaddingTop;
    if (offsetRequired) top += getTopPaddingOffset();
    return top;
}
```

In this method, `top` is calculated by adding value of topOffSet when offset is needed. So to reverse the effect we need to pass negative value of padding which you are passing. so we need to return `-getPaddingTop()`.

Now for bottom we are not passing negative value because bottom is working on `top + height`. So passing negative value make fade more shorter from the bottom so we need to add bottom padding to make it proper visible.

You can override this 4 method to play with it. `getLeftPaddingOffset(), getRightPaddingOffset(), getTopPaddingOffset(), getBottomPaddingOffset()`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a few solutions
, I hope to be helpful

**1- RecyclerView.ItemDecoration** (keep `requiresFadingEdge`)

```
class ItemDecoration(private val spacing: Int) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration(){

   override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: 
   RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State?) {

   val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
   when(position)
    0 ->                          { outRect.top    = spacing /*40dp*/ }
    parent.adapter.itemCount-1 -> { outRect.bottom = spacing /*40dp*/ }

}
```

**2- Multiple ViewHolders** (depending on the ViewHolder either keep or remove `requiresFadingEdge`)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/5255963

**3- Gradient** (remove `requiresFadingEdge`)

Make two gradients with drawables like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:type="linear"
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="#000"
    android:endColor="#FFF" />
</shape>
```

And set `background` to two views at the top and bottom of the Recyclerview.

Comment: The 3rd solution isn't enough efficient, so it makes overdraw

Comment: The first solution is good to solve this problem, simple and elegant.

Comment: Java version of the first answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve that but I preferred below solution that works for me.
You can use a third-party library called `Android-FadingEdgeLayout` checkout [here](https://github.com/bosphere/Android-FadingEdgeLayout)

Here is a dependency.

```
implementation 'com.github.bosphere.android-fadingedgelayout:fadingedgelayout:1.0.0'
```

In yours.xml

```
<com.bosphere.fadingedgelayout.FadingEdgeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fading_edge_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:fel_edge="top|left|bottom|right"
    app:fel_size_top="40dp"
    app:fel_size_bottom="40dp"
    app:fel_size_left="0dp"
    app:fel_size_right="0dp">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView   
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false" />

</com.bosphere.fadingedgelayout.FadingEdgeLayout>
```

Change your `ReacyclerView` property according to your need. below is example image with all sided sades. I hope that will help you.

[image]

Credits [Android-FadingEdgeLayout](https://github.com/bosphere/Android-FadingEdgeLayout)